# Dipole moments of dibromoethene isomers

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, dipole

There was an exercise in my textbook asking to compare the dipole moments of 1,1-dibromoethene and 1,2-dibromoethene(Z). The answer in the textbook says that the dipole moment of 1,1-dibromoethene is greater than that of 1,2-dibromoethene.

This seems counter-intuitive as the angle between the dipole moments of the two $\ce{C-Br}$ bonds in 1,1-dibromoethene is $120°$ and that in 1,2-dibromoethene(Z) is $60°$. A little physics tells us that the net dipole moment of 1,2-dibromoethene should be greater than that of 1,1-dibromoethene which contradicts the answer in the textbook. I want to know whether I am correct or not.

Comment: There is also the dipole moment of C-C bond.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/133337/which-has-greater-dipole-moment-cis-1-2-dichloroethylene-or-1-1-dichloroethylen